# How do I convert a Json file (that contains a array) to a List (of a class object) C# Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

i'm using a NewtonSoft Json API to read my dialogue texts and i'm having problem to populate a List of dialogues information.

i would like to populate my list (of this class below) using  one of this 2 Json formats.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DialogueList
{
    public string dialogueName;
    public bool isDialogueOption;
    public string[] dialogueText;

    public string option1;
    public string option2;
}
```

Ex: I would like if the list be like this.

```
//(Slot 1)
dialogueList[0].dialogueName = "Nyma";
dialogueList[0].isDialogueOption = true;
dialogueList[0].dialogueText[0] = "Hi Xire! how are you?";
dialogueList[0].dialogueText[1] = "Hi Nyma! i'm fine and you?";

dialogueList[0].option1 = "Fine!";
dialogueList[0].option2 = "I'm not fine!";

//(Slot2)
dialogueList[1].dialogueName = "Xire";
dialogueList[1].isDialogueOption = false;
dialogueList[1].dialogueText[0] = "Run Nyma";
dialogueList[1].dialogueText[1] = "I'm Running Xire";

dialogueList[1].option1 = Null;
dialogueList[1].option2 = Null;
```

Json Format 1:

```
{
  "Dialogue_Nyma": [
    {
      "dialogueName": "Nyma",
      "isDialogueOption": true,
      "dialogueText": [
        "Hi Xire! how are you?",
        "Hi Nyma! i'm fine and you?"
      ],
      "Option1": "Fine!",
      "Option2": "i'm not fine!"
    }
  ],
  "Dialogue_Xire": [
    {
      "dialogueName": "Xire",
      "isDialogueOption": false,
      "dialogueText": [
        "Run Nyma!",
        "i'm Running Xire."
      ],
      "Option1": null,
      "Option2": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Json format 2:

```
[
  {
    "dialogueName": "Nyma",
    "isDialogueOption": true,
    "dialogueText": [
      "Hi Xire! how are you?",
      "Hi Nyma! i'm fine and you?"
    ],
    "Option1": "Fine!",
    "Option2": "i'm not fine!"
  },
  {
    "dialogueName": "Xire",
    "isDialogueOption": false,
    "dialogueText": [
      "Run Nyma!",
      "i'm Running Xire."
    ],
    "Option1": null,
    "Option2": null
  }
]
```

If someone could help me to find a way to deserialize one of these json formats to populate my list i'll be really thankful!

i also tried to create a class that contains a array of Dialogue List

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DialogueListCollection
{
    public DialogueList[] dialogueList;
}
```

and tried to parse like this

```
string path = "DialogueJson/Textos";
var contents = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
dialogueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DialogueListCollection>(contents.text);
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should represent the dialog:

```
public class Dialogue
{
    public string dialogueName;
    public bool isDialogueOption;
    public string[] dialogueText;

    public string option1;
    public string option2;
}
```

(Notice the "List" is gone from the class name)

You can then use Newtonsoft to deserialize it to an array:

```
var json = @"[
  {
    ""dialogueName"": ""Nyma"",
    ""isDialogueOption"": true,
    ""dialogueText"": [
      ""Hi Xire! how are you?"",
      ""Hi Nyma! i'm fine and you?""
    ],
    ""Option1"": ""Fine!"",
    ""Option2"": ""i'm not fine!""
  },
  {
    ""dialogueName"": ""Xire"",
    ""isDialogueOption"": false,
    ""dialogueText"": [
      ""Run Nyma!"",
      ""i'm Running Xire.""
    ],
    ""Option1"": null,
    ""Option2"": null
  }
]";

Dialogue[] list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dialogue[]>(json);
```

Your array `list` now contains two entries.

The second format you provided is correctly formatted and used in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

Add class that will contain only array of DialogueList and parse json as this class. You'll need to add one field in json to put list in it.

Comment: i have a class (DialogueListCollection) that contains a array of Dialogue List, and i'm trying to parse like this but wont work.

'
            string path = "DialogueJson/Textos";
            var contents = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);
            dialogueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DialogueListCollection>(contents.text);
'